# How to obtain the ListItem inside a CheckBoxList which triggered the postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, onclick, checkboxlist

I have two CheckBoxLists and I need to be able to set the ListItems selected in one of the CheckBoxList depending on the items selected in the other CheckBoxList.

How can I know which ListItem inside a CheckBoxList had issued the postback? The method must be run at server.

**SOLUTION UPDATE:**

Final solution i used (thanks to Four):

```
protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItem = CheckBoxList1.SelectedItem;
}
```

Where selectedItem is the ListItem that was clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much simpler:

```
var selectedItem = CheckBoxList1.SelectedItem;
```

Comment: Not a problem, I always try to thing there are solutions like this to problems in .NET. When we write allot of code for a simple task, it's often a sign we missed something like that.

Comment: yeah, it's true :) it must have been simple cause it was basic functionality, i must remember this ^^

Comment: That is wrong I'm afraid. SelectedItem returns the first one that was selected by its lower index... If you only select one from the list (then it will work, after many selections with higher index it will always return the one with the lower index... sorry for my english

Comment: You have to cast the sender in the OnSelectedIndexChanged like this

Answer (score 3):

Set the AutoPostBack property to True and then make and changes you need to do on the server: [How to use AutoPostBack feature in CheckBoxList](http://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2009/03/how-to-use-autopostback-feature-in.html)

```
<asp:CheckBoxList   
         ID="CheckBoxList1"  
         runat="server"  
         AutoPostBack="true"  
         OnSelectedIndexChanged="CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChnaged"  
>
```

To see which ListItems have been checked, you can iterate through the CheckBoxList as follows:

```
protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChnaged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)  
{  
    Label1.Text = "You Selected:<br /><i>";  
    foreach (ListItem li in CheckBoxList1.Items)  
    {  
        if (li.Selected == true)  
        {  
            Label1.Text += li.Text + "<br />";  
        }  
    }  
    Label1.Text += "</i>";  
}
```

To get the value of the ListItem that was checked without iterating through all ListItems, you can do the following:

```
protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBoxList list = (CheckBoxList)sender;
    string[] control = Request.Form.Get("__EVENTTARGET").Split('$');
    int index = control.Length - 1;
    ListItem li = (ListItem)list.Items[Int32.Parse(control[index])];
}
```

At this point you'll have the actual ListItem that was checked and you can do with it whatever you please.

Comment: i need an event that will allow me to access the ListItem which i clicked

Comment: i know that but i need to know specifically which item has been checked/unchecked without using a state variable :)

Comment: @Răzvan Panda: I've updated my answer to give you the actual ListItem that has been checked.

Comment: cool, it works but why did you take the index as the last value in the control array? is it possible to have more than one __EVENTTARGET in the Request.Form?